Horizontal Angle Transmission in Ray Tracing Program - MatLab
I am working on a simulation of underwater sound propagation in MatLab. Currently, the program works in 2D, however, I am trying to transition it into 3D.
Without just copying all 100+ lines of the program, I'll try to briefly explain how angle transmission currently works, and what it looks like.
Transmission_Angle_Range = deg2rad(0:1:16);
Simulation_Steps = 20;
Simulation_Range = 0:Simulation_Steps:50000;
num_angles = length(transmission_angle_grid);
num_steps = length(Simulation_Range);

The above lines are used to make arrays for transmitting angles and for the range of the simulation, they are then iterated over in the following manner:
% Simulation loop
for j=2:num_steps
    for i=1:num_angles
        if (z(i, j-1) == Source_Depth) && (theta(i, j-1) == 0)
            c(i, j) = Source_Sound_Speed;
            theta(i, j) = 0;
            z(i, j) = Source_Depth;
            % ...further ray tracing logic here...

Where z = depth, c = speed of sound, and theta = angle. Once the loop concludes, the program will plot z against the simulation range in order to view the path the rays take. Currently, viewing this plot in 3D results in the following:

My question comes here, as can be seen, the angles essentially form one flat plane along the diagonal. I was wondering how I could make it so angles will also transmit in different directions starting from the origin. I'll add an image here to clarify what I mean:

Essentially, I want to make it so angles are transmitted in different horizontal directions so that it is propagating along the cube rather than just one flat plane.
If any other code snippets or explanations are necessary, please let me know, and thank you!
